# Which is this Parametrized Surface?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry, surfaces, parametrization

I just have not gotten the gist of parametric curves yet. I don't quite understand how to go from a vector $R(u,t)$ to an equation or vice-versa. So, if you guys could help me with the following:

> Identify the surface $r(u, v) = \langle\sqrt{v} \sin(u), v\cos^2(u), \sqrt{v})\rangle$.

This stuff is immensely hard for me, so please go lightly (I'm new here!). Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

We have $x^2+y=v\sin^2 u+v\cos^2 u=v=z^2$. This is an equation of a hyperbolic [paraboloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraboloid).